# GORM prevent creation of a foreign key constraint for a Domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm, foreign-key-relationship

I am developing a web based application in Grails. I have come across a situation where I would like to try and suppress GORM from creating a foreign key constraint on a field in a table.

I have a domain class which is part of a class hierarchy. The domain class essentially acts as a link to a target domain. The target domain can be of different types and each of the subclasses of this link domain is designed to provide the link for each specific type of linked item. These linked items have certain behaviour in common i.e. implement the same interface but otherwise are different to the point that they are stored in different tables.

Within this link domain table there is one column which represents the id of the item being linked to. All the linked items have the same integer based id. The problem is that GORM tries to create multiple foreign key constraints of this same table column, one for each of the link domain subclasses which represents a different type of linked item. I know I could have separate columns for the id of each time where the other id columns would be null but this seems kind of messy. If there were a way to just tell GORM I don't want it to create a foreign key constraint on that column (because different foreign keys use the same column) that would solve the problem.

I know that the question comes up of referential integrity and whether a link key value  could be put in the column which does not exist in the foreign table but the application should prevent this situation from occurring.

failing this then I would have to deal with loading the linked item manually and not rely on GORM to do it automatically.

Comment: can you please post some classes and expected tables?  You described what you want in detail, but its better with classes.  I might be able to help more than my first answer if you do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a relatively short googling I found Burt Beckwith's blog entry: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=465 that explains the basics of GORM customization. With the following configuration class I managed to prevent creation of a key I did not want to get created. In Burt's example a RootClass is required, but this did not suit my needs so the checking is omitted.

```
package com.myapp;

import com.myapp.objects.SomeClass;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.MappingException;
import org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey;
import org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass;
import org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DomainConfiguration extends GrailsAnnotationConfiguration {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    private boolean _alreadyProcessed;

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    @Override
    protected void secondPassCompile() throws MappingException {
        super.secondPassCompile();

        if(_alreadyProcessed) {
            return;
        }

        Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DomainConfiguration.class.getName());

        for(PersistentClass pc : (Collection<PersistentClass>) classes.values()) {
            boolean preventFkCreation = false;
            String fkReferencedEntityNameToPrevent = null;

            if("com.myapp.objects.SomeClassWithUnwantedFkThatHasSomeClassAsAMember".equals(pc.getClassName())) {
                preventFkCreation = true;
                fkReferencedEntityNameToPrevent = SomeClass.class.getName();
            }

            if(preventFkCreation) {
                for(Iterator iter = pc.getTable().getForeignKeyIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
                    ForeignKey fk = (ForeignKey) iter.next();

                    if(fk.getReferencedEntityName().equals(fkReferencedEntityNameToPrevent)) {
                        iter.remove();
                        log.info("Prevented creation of foreign key referencing " + fkReferencedEntityNameToPrevent + " in " + pc.getClassName() + ".");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        _alreadyProcessed = true;
    }
}
```

The configuration class is introduced to Grails by putting it to datasource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    ...
    ...
    configClass = 'com.myapp.DomainConfiguration
}
```

Comment: Do you have a similar solution for Grails 3 with Hibernate 5?

Comment: @Viriato Unfortunately no.

Comment: I added another answer for Grails 3 / Hibernate 5.

Answer (score 1):

For those struggling with this problem using Grails 3 with gorm-hibernate5, I found a solution based on Graeme's comment on [grails-data-mapping #880](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/880).

I implemented a custom SchemaManagementTool and added it to the application configuration:

```
hibernate.schema_management_tool = CustomSchemaManagementTool
```

The Hibernate SchemaManagementTool ultimately delegates the raw SQL commands to a GenerationTarget (typically [GenerationTargetToDatabase](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tool/schema/internal/exec/GenerationTargetToDatabase.java)), so our goal is to provide our own GenerationTarget.

This would be easiest if we could override HibernateSchemaManagementTool.buildGenerationTargets, but this is unfortunately not exposed. Instead, we need to develop our own SchemaCreator and SchemaDropper and return them in the CustomSchemaManagementTool:

```
class CustomSchemaManagementTool extends HibernateSchemaManagementTool {
    @Override
    SchemaCreator getSchemaCreator(Map options) {
        return new CustomSchemaCreator(this, getSchemaFilterProvider(options).getCreateFilter())
    }

    @Override
    SchemaDropper getSchemaDropper(Map options) {
        return new CustomSchemaDropper(this, getSchemaFilterProvider(options).getDropFilter())
    }

    // We unfortunately copy this private method from HibernateSchemaManagementTool
    private SchemaFilterProvider getSchemaFilterProvider(Map options) {
        final Object configuredOption = (options == null) ? null : options.get(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_FILTER_PROVIDER)
        return serviceRegistry.getService(StrategySelector.class).resolveDefaultableStrategy(
            SchemaFilterProvider.class,
            configuredOption,
            DefaultSchemaFilterProvider.INSTANCE
        )
    }
}
```

For the SchemaCreator and SchemaDropper implementation, we can override doCreation and doDrop respectively. These are essentially copied from the Hibernate implementations, but with a CustomGenerationTarget instead of GenerationTargetToDatabase:

```
class CustomSchemaCreator extends SchemaCreatorImpl {
    private final HibernateSchemaManagementTool tool

    CustomSchemaCreator(HibernateSchemaManagementTool tool, SchemaFilter schemaFilter) {
        super(tool, schemaFilter)
        this.tool = tool
    }

    @Override
    void doCreation(Metadata metadata, ExecutionOptions options, SourceDescriptor sourceDescriptor, TargetDescriptor targetDescriptor) {
        final JdbcContext jdbcContext = tool.resolveJdbcContext( options.getConfigurationValues() )
        final GenerationTarget[] targets = new GenerationTarget[ targetDescriptor.getTargetTypes().size() ]
        targets[0] = new CustomGenerationTarget(tool.getDdlTransactionIsolator(jdbcContext), true)
        super.doCreation(metadata, jdbcContext.getDialect(), options, sourceDescriptor, targets)
    }
}

class CustomSchemaDropper extends SchemaDropperImpl {
    private final HibernateSchemaManagementTool tool

    CustomSchemaDropper(HibernateSchemaManagementTool tool, SchemaFilter schemaFilter) {
        super(tool, schemaFilter)
        this.tool = tool
    }

    @Override
    void doDrop(Metadata metadata, ExecutionOptions options, SourceDescriptor sourceDescriptor, TargetDescriptor targetDescriptor) {
        final JdbcContext jdbcContext = tool.resolveJdbcContext( options.getConfigurationValues() )
        final GenerationTarget[] targets = new GenerationTarget[ targetDescriptor.getTargetTypes().size() ]
        targets[0] = new CustomGenerationTarget(tool.getDdlTransactionIsolator(jdbcContext), true)
        super.doDrop(metadata, options, jdbcContext.getDialect(), sourceDescriptor, targets)
    }
}
```

In this case I use the same CustomGenerationTarget for both create and drop, but you could easily split this up into different classes. Now we finally get the payoff by extending GenerationTargetToDatabase and overriding the accept method. By only calling **super.accept** on SQL statements to keep, you can filter out undesired DDL statements.

```
class CustomGenerationTarget extends GenerationTargetToDatabase {
    CustomGenerationTarget(DdlTransactionIsolator ddlTransactionIsolator, boolean releaseAfterUse) {
        super(ddlTransactionIsolator, releaseAfterUse)
    }

    @Override
    void accept(String command) {
        if (shouldAccept(command))
            super.accept(command)
    }

    boolean shouldAccept(String command) {
        // Custom filtering logic here, e.g.:
        if (command =~ /references legacy\.xyz/)
            return false
        return true
    }
}
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but you can get the job done.

I also tried providing my own SchemaFilterProvider (and a custom [SchemaFilter](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/SchemaFilter.java)). This unfortunately only allows filtering of tables/namespaces - not foreign keys.

Comment: I will give this a try but where in your solution it states to remove the foreign keys? It is not clear to me by looking at the 4 classes you provided. In the grails 2 solution above I also have it so that it removes checkconstraints, indexes unique keys and columns from the PersistentClass object from domains under a certain package. This is to make sure that our mapped vendor tables do not get modified in any way (even in develop enviroment) by Grails.

Comment: The foreign keys are filtered (not passed to super) in the CustomGenerationTarget.accept method. In this case I'm looking for "references legacy.xyz" SQL statements (PostgreSQL foreign key statement).

Comment: so we were able to test it out and we were able to filter out the fk generation when running in "create-drop" mode but when we run in dbCreate = "update" mode the accept method never gets hit. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Viriato SchemaManagementTool also has a getSchemaMigrator method that I did not override in this example. Maybe that is called for dbCreate = "update"?

Comment: did you successfully get that to work on your project? I have added a getSchemaMigrator to the custom managment tool and told it to use the CustomSchemaMigrator that takes in a  targets[0] = new CustomGenerationTarget in the doMigration overriden mehtod but I run into internal exceptions any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at this section of the documentation

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.2 Custom ORM Mapping

you can override grails's default persistence semantics by using the custom mapping DSL.

Comment: I have read through the section and already use the custom mapping DSL quite extensively in my application. I have been searching through the documentation for some time but haven't found mention of ways of changing the foreign key creation behaviour. I am beginning to suspect that what I want to do is not currently possible.